# Why is the $PAM_RHOST env var not set by openssh-server

Tags: ssh, pam

I have a script running called from `/etc/pam.d/sshd` with the following line:

```
session    optional     pam_exec.so /usr/local/bin/notify-login
```

The script gets called as expected everytime someone logged in via ssh. But since August 2016 the `$PAM_RHOST` env var is not set anymore. I couldn't find something in the changelogs that explains this behavior.

Can someone please give me a hint where to look or present me a solution how to fix or work around this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have been relying on this environment variable and it has now gone away, then I think the thing to do is to submit a bug report to whichever OS/Distro you are using.